# LINQ - How to Change / Convert FirstOrDefault() tolist() or SelectMany()

Tags: c#, linq, serialization

I have the following LINQ query,where every line doing some stuff , but that line Serial No i also Marked with ** it will be return First Or Default or just one row ,But that column (Serial No) in my database has to many rows not just one , which means if we have 10 items for ex 10 Lenovo Keyboard in database, its means we have 10 different Serial No for each Keyboard ,But the query i wrote it will be show just First Serial No, so how can i change that to show all/rows of Serial No! Can anyone direct me in the right direction? thx

**PS When i change FirstOrDefault into tolist() i will get error under this line SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre = t.SerialNo.Serial_No_, | error is about system collections generic list does not contain a definition for Serial_No_

Action And Query:

```
var col2 = data_2.Shipment.Where(t => t.Order_No_ == OrdreNo).Select(t => new
                {
                    **SerialNo = data_2.Serial_Numbers.Where(ledger => ledger.Document_No_ == t.Document_No_)
                            .Where(ledger => ledger.Document_Line_No_ == t.Line_No_)
                            .toList(),

                });

var bla3 = col2.Select(t => new Ordre_Open_Details_VM.OrdreDetailDeliveryLineOpen
                {
                 **SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre = t.SerialNo.Select(x=>x.Serial_No_).ToList(), ** //Serial No

                })
            .ToList();
```

Class:

```
 public OrdreDetailDeliveryLineOpen(List<string> SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre)
                        {
     ** this.SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre = SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre;**

      }
         }

     ** public List <string> SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre { get; set; } **  
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem when you change `FirstOrDefault` into `ToList()`?

Comment: @Pikoh will get error under this line SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre = t.SerialNo.Serial_No_, | error is about system collections generic list does not contain a definition for Serial_No_

Comment: Of course, because then it is a List. If there are several Serial numbers, how do you want to asign them to a single `SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre` variable? It would work if you change that line into `SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre = t.SerialNo.FirstOrDefault().Serial_No_,`

Comment: Or better, you'll need to change your `SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre` property type to `List<T>`

Comment: i make changes to that Query SerialNo into tolist() , and than i changed that line SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre = t.SerialNo.FirstOrDefault().Serial_No_, , its same like before , but let me try your second comment

Comment: @Pikoh i just tried but it's complicated , beacuse OrdreDetailDeliveryLineOpen its list and all property is under that class , but i want change singel property to list and i get errors , but let me update my question with class

Comment: @Pikoh i just update my question with class

Comment: If you have a list, but you want just a single property, you have to decide yourself _which_ item from the list you want. If you want to do something with all items in the list, you should write a loop to do that. You can _not_ magically perform a single action on a single item and expect it to work for a whole list. So what do you want? Do something with one item or so something with all items in a list?

Comment: i want do something with one itme (Serial No) which is wrap it in a list :)

Comment: Or i put result of all item into a list , but there is one item i interesting have list of that , which is Serial No

Comment: I cannot follow you. Do you want to do something with _one_ Serial No, or do you want to do something with _a list of Serial Nos_? And _what_ do you want to do with it/them?

Comment: If you define a field _SerialNo_ as a single object, you cannot assign a list to it. If you want to assign a list to something, define that something as a list. `public string SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre { get; set; }` can only contains 1 item. If you want more items in it, make it something like `public List<string> SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre { get; set; }`.

Comment: you have to change type of Serial_No to list as mentioned above or just select one number - .First(x=>x.?==??) instead of .FirstOrDefault()

Comment: you want to put multiple cars into one garage. either make the garage a parking house (List of garages) to fit multiple cars or decide one car that should park in the garage. Car = item you select, garage= type of serial number.

Comment: @oerkelens thats wat i was looking for , i change my class , what about my action  how can i change them ?! i mean this to lines :  **SerialNo = data_2.Item_Ledger_Entry.Where(ledger => ledger.Document_No_ == t.Document_No_)
                    .Where(ledger => ledger.Document_Line_No_ == t.Line_No_)
                    .FirstOrDefault(), | and this line **SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre = t.SerialNo.Serial_No_, ** //Serial No

Comment: @oerkelens i also update the class ,where u see whats happend :-)

Comment: What happens if you just change FirtsOrDefault() to ToList() there? SerialNo should become a list, and later on t.SerialNo should be assignable to SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre. Not that you have _lists everywhere then, so  t.SerialNo.Serial_No_ still makes _no sense whatsoever!_

Comment: @oerkelens i just update the class in my question ,would you please look into it :) :) and i change  FirtsOrDefault() to ToList() , But i get this error under  SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre = t.SerialNo.Serial_No and this error > Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DBhandling.Item_Ledger_Entry>' does not contain a definition for 'Serial_No' and no extension method 'Serial_No' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DBhandling.Item_Ledger_Entry>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: One last time: `t.SerialNo` is a **List**. It contains multiple items. It does not have a property `Serial_No`. Take a break, and then think what you want to do with that **List**. You do _not_ want to get _one_ serialnumber out of the **list** of serialsnumbers, so you have to figure out what to do with the whole **List** of serialnumbers. Why don't you start with `SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre = t.SerialNo`? Then think what you want to do with your 'SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre' which is now also a **List**.

Comment: @oerkelens sorry i didnt mean to bothering you or ... i just wanna try to figure out . i did i changed the query to >  SerialNo= data_2.Item_Ledger_Entry.Where(ledger => ledger.Document_No_ == t.Document_No_).Where(ledger=> ledger.Document_Line_No_ == t.Line_No_).ToList() and than i changed SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre = t.SerialNo , but i get error under t.SerialNo > Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DBhandling.Item_Ledger_Entry>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' and than i changed to t.SerialNo.Select(x=>x.Serial_No_).ToList() ,No more error But

Comment: @oerkelens But in browser instead showing Serialnumbers its just showing this text > System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Comment: Then in your browser you are trying to show a list of serial numbers as one single string. What do you _expect_ to see? One number or a _list of numbers_?

Comment: @oerkelens i wanna show list of numbers

Comment: @oerkelens i also update the code to better see,whats happend

Comment: Ok, so now the question becomes "how do I represent a list of numbers in my front end?" There is no front-end code in your question, I suggest you ask a new question with the necessary information and code.

Comment: @oerkelens i will do that for sure , but there is code in front : foreach (var FieldShipment in Model.OrdreDetailDeliveryLineOpens)
                                {<td>@FieldShipment.SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre</td>}

Comment: Or foreach (var FieldShipment in Model.OrdreDetailDeliveryLineOpens) {<ul><li>@FieldShipment.SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre</li></ul>} –

Comment: So you want another foreach.`foreach (var FieldShipment in Model.OrdreDetailDeliveryLineOpens) {<ul>foreach(var x in FieldShipment.SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre){<li>@x</li>}</‌​ul>}`. You are working with a list, so make a List Item for each item in the list instead of just throwing the whole list at it as if it is one single field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a long discussion in the comments, this seems to work:

1) Define SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre as a `List<string>` instead of a `string`:

```
public List <string> SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre { get; set; }
```

2) Assign a list to SerialNo:

```
SerialNo = data_2.Item_Ledger_Entry.Where(ledger => ledger.Document_No_ == t.Document_No_)
                .Where(ledger => ledger.Document_Line_No_ == t.Line_No_).ToList();
```

3) Assign a List to the new `SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre`

```
SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre = t.SerialNo.Select(x=>x.Serial_No_).ToList(),
```

4) Then, to render the list in your front end, loop over the list-items:

```
foreach (var FieldShipment in Model.OrdreDetailDeliveryLineOpens)
{
    <ul>
    foreach(var x in FieldShipment.SerialNoDeliverdLineOpenOrdre)
    {
       <li>@x</li>
    }
    </‌‌​​ul>
}
```